# How to set my screen to 144Hz

Tags: manjaro

I have an LG screen capable of WQHD and 144Hz. My problem that I can set it only to WQHD and 100Hz using HDMI and the integrated Vega 11 GPU. With a dedicated graphics card I had the 144Hz option, but with this Vega I have only 100Hz, 75Hz, 60Hz in the screen settings. Is it possible to add the 144Hz option somehow?

Comment: The vega 8 is quite old, from 2018, and may not have the bandwidth at it's outputs for 1440p 144Hz. If the machine only has HDMI 1.4 outputs then it will be limited at the port and there is nothing you can do.

Comment: @Mokubai Ohh sorry, it is vega 11, I fixed the question. In theory the HDMI cable is and the motherboard is good for 144Hz.

Comment: That doesn't really change much, they're just different GPUs in the same range. If your system only supports HDMI 1.4 then 144Hz may well be out of reach at 1440p. You can see the calculations at (enter your resolution at the top and scroll down to the HDMI section) https://tomverbeure.github.io/video_timings_calculator you might be able to change your display output to YUV 4:2:2 somewhere but it is at the loss of *some* image quality that may be imperceptible. Even HDMI 2.0 requires DSC (display stream compression) to manage 144Hz at 1440p. Out of preference your machine needs HDMI 2.1